# How to create the TypeScript types declarations for multiples modules of existing library?

Tags: typescript

I began to create the TypeScript types definitions for [pug-lint](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-lint) package. Most of API is in `lib` directory:

[image]

The `const PugLint = require("pug-lint")` will import the `linter.js` (third one from the bottom).
I began to create the annotation for this file according to [Module: Class template](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html):

```js
export as namespace pugLint;


export = PugLint;


declare class PugLint {
    constructor();

    configure(config: PugLint.Config): void;
    checkFile(file: VinylFile): Array<PugLint.RawError>;
    // TODO
}


declare namespace PugLint {
    export interface Config {
      // TODO
    }

    export interface RawError {
        code: string;
        msg: string;
        line: number;
        column: number;
        filename: string;
        src: string;
        toJSON(): NormalizedError;
    }

    export interface NormalizedError {
        code: string;
        msg: string;
        line: number;
        column: number;
        filename: string;
    }
}
```

The completing of above file is just matter of time, but how to annotate the rest files (`config-file.js`, `errors.js`, etc.)? I did not find the direct answer on this question and first tried by shot in the dark method adding the below code to `index.d.ts`:

```js
declare module "pug-lint/lib/config-file" {
    declare function load(config: unknown, cwd?: string): PugLint.Config | undefined;
}
```

I created the access to unpublished yet `@types/pug-lint` by symlinks. Now the `import PugLint from "pug-lint";` is visible for TypeScript, but `import PugLintConfigFile from "pug-lint/lib/config-file";` is not visible:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to mirror the directory layout in your type declarations. So create `lib/config-file.d.ts` containing `export function load(...)`.
Here are couple of examples of similar multi-file type declarations:

- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-bootstrap
- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/ol

The other alternative is to place everything in single `index.d.ts` file, each part wrapped inside `declare module`:

```
declare module 'pug-lint' {
  export = PugLint;
  class PugLint {...}
}
declare module 'pug-lint/lib/config-file' {
  export function load(): undefined
}
```

Here are some examples using this pattern:

- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/material-ui/index.d.ts
- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pkijs/index.d.ts